# PHP: Simple way to rearrange array with repetitive keys

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array like this one:

```
0 => Array ( [invoice_id] => 376 [discount_id] => 1 [product_id] => 15 ),
1 => Array ( [invoice_id] => 376 [discount_id] => 5 [product_id] => 16 ),
2 => Array ( [invoice_id] => 376 [discount_id] => 7 [product_id] => 17 ),
3 => Array ( [invoice_id] => 254 [discount_id] => 13 [product_id] => 26 ),
4 => Array ( [invoice_id] => 254 [discount_id] => 3 [product_id] => 33 ),
```

And I want this array to look like this one:

```
376 => Array (0 => Array( [discount_id] => 1 [product_id] => 15 ),
              1 => Array( [discount_id] => 5 [product_id] => 16 ),
              2 => Array( [discount_id] => 7 [product_id] => 17 )),
254 => Array (0 => Array ([discount_id] => 13 [product_id] => 26),
              1 => Array ([discount_id] => 3 [product_id] => 33))
```

I would like to know what is the simplest, best, and most elegant way to do this?

Comment: The array you currently have would be an illegal array in PHP, because the keys are duplicated..... what array do you ___really___ have?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, I'm editting it right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is complete example. Just copy and paste:

```
$arrInput = array(
        0 => Array ( 'invoice_id' => 376, 'discount_id' => 1 ,'product_id' => 15 ),
        1 => Array ( 'invoice_id' => 376, 'discount_id' => 5, 'product_id' => 16 ),
        2 => Array ( 'invoice_id' => 376 ,'discount_id' => 7 ,'product_id' => 17 ),
        3 => Array ( 'invoice_id' => 254, 'discount_id' => 13, 'product_id' => 26 ),
        4 => Array ( 'invoice_id' => 254, 'discount_id' => 3 ,'product_id' => 33 ));


$res = group($arrInput, 'invoice_id');

print_r("<pre>");
print_r($res);


function group($data, $column)
{
$arrRes = array();
foreach($data as $row)
{
    if (!is_array($arrRes[$row[$column]]))
    {
        $arrRes[$row[$column]] = array();
    }
    $arrRes[$row[$column]][] = $row;
}
return $arrRes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are similar keys `'invoice1' , 'invoice2'` only the last value will be there in the array as `'invoice1' => 'product4' and 'invoice2' => 'product3'`. You won't be able to get an array like in the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myNewArray = array();
foreach($myBigArrayThatIWantRestructuring as $value) {
    if (!isset($myNewArray[$value['invoice_id']])) {
        $myNewArray[$value['invoice_id']] = array();
    }
    $myNewArray[$value['invoice_id']][] = array(
        'discount_id' => $value['discount_id'],
        'product_id' => $value['product_id'],
    );
}
```